# r grepl search for multiple patterns in a variable

Tags: regex, r, pattern-matching, grepl

I'm trying to search into a string variable and every time a determinate pattern is found the search funtion tell me TRUE. I'm using grepl to find the match:

```
grepl(pattern,x)
```

The pattern needs to be build from several words that, in turn are captured from a csv file.

I guess I'm doing something wrong building the pattern, but I can't find the error.

Below there is a fictional example

```
#example file with the string data to classify
des<-c("DDD SS","FFFFF P","AAA EKO BBB","KK SUPER OO","JJ")
num<-c(5,6,2,7,9)
d0<-data.frame(des,num)


#example file with the pattern to search for as rows
t0<-data.frame(c("SUPER","A ISABEL","EKO"))

t1<-as.list(t(t0)) #traspose the vector as la list
t2<-do.call("paste",c(t1,sep="'|'")) #collapse to a single string with '|' (or) symbol for the grepl pattern

cl<-grepl(t2,d0$des)
```

The final grepl does not find any match

```
> cl
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 t2 <- paste(t1, collapse="|")
 grepl(t2, d0$des)
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```